# Surface Area Line integral problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

I'm trying to figure out how to solve a surface area with surface and line integrals (showing both methods).

The area I'm trying to compute is the area of the shape $$x^2+y^2=9$$ bounded by $z=0$ and $z=y$. (Note: $y \ge 0$).

I've started the problem by making a parametrization: 
$$ r(u,v) = \langle 3\cos v, 3\sin v, u\rangle $$ from $0 \leq u \leq 3\sin v$ and $-\frac{ \pi}{3} \leq v \leq \pi$. The magnitude of $|r_u \times r_v| = 3$.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Do you mean the volume?

Comment: No, surface area of the piece of this cylinder.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $3\cos v$ instead? otherwise $x^2+y^2\neq 9$

Comment: @s3wix A little-known LaTeX tip: You can use \langle and \rangle (in left-and-right pairs) to get $\langle \ \ \  \rangle$ instead of using the inequality symbols < and > which give $<$ and $>$

Answer (score 0):

The surface integral is given by:
$$\iint \left\| 
{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x}\times {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial y} 
\right\| dx\, dy$$
Now when you transfer to cylindrical coordinates, you must convert your derivatives and add the Jacobian, so you must convert:
$${\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x}={\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial u}\cdot{\partial u \over \partial x} + {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial v}\cdot{\partial v \over \partial x}$$ And similar for $y$. Also, 
$$dx\, dy=u\, du\, dv$$
Put everything together and you should get your result.

Comment: Why does dxdy = ududv?

Comment: @s3wix - because that's the Jacobian for cylindrical coordinates, see here for instance:

http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/jacpol/jacpol.html